# can't open recovery menu after installing recovery clockworkmod 5.0.2.6 galaxy ace fix

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, 2.3-gingerbread, 4.1-jelly-bean, clockworkmod-recovery

I have installed `clockworkmod-5.0.2.6-galacyace-fix.zip` on Samsung galaxy ace s5830.

When I had rebooted it and pressed <kbd>Home</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd> button, it is not showing me a recovery menu. When I press <kbd>Home</kbd>+<kbd>VolumeUp</kbd>+<kbd>Power</kbd>, it is showing me only logo of "Samsung" and on left hand side corner showing me "ramdump" arm mode 9.

I don't know now what to do? I want to update it. I have tried Jelly bean but it is only showing the Samsung logo after rebooting it. Others downloads like GingerBread and all are aborted while installing. My phone still can not be started.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried wiping after flashing?

Comment: You mean after installing a new os, i need to wipe out whole data of phone once again! Right now there is no os installed on my phone and i have tried to install clockwork recovery, after that my recovery menu can't open! When I press Home+Power button then only samsung logo appears.That means there is something problem in booting loop. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes - a boot loop is normally solved by a data wipe.

Comment: right now my problem is that i can't open recovery menu. So how can i wipe out data? Can you tell me an alternative for opening a recovery menu?

Comment: Try run from console `reboot recovery` or from PC: `adb reboot recovery`. Is recovery starting?

Comment: thanks..i had given my phone to samsung shop!they told me there was a problem in my chip! So they have installed a new circuit!